# Error while using JCS : Failed to retrieve javax.sql:jdbc-stdext-2.0

Tags: java, maven, caching, jdbc, jcs

While downloading JCS using Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jcs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcs</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**Error :**

```
[WARNING] An error occurred during dependency resolution.
    Failed to retrieve javax.sql:jdbc-stdext-2.0
Caused by: Failure to find javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the upd
ate interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
Try downloading the file manually from:
    http://java.sun.com/products/jdbc/download.html
Then, install it using the command:
    mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.sql -DartifactId=jdbc-stdext -Dversion=2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
    mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=javax.sql -DartifactId=jdbc-stdext -Dversion=2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
Path to dependency:
        1) com.samsung.jcs:jcs_demo:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) jcs:jcs:jar:1.3
        3) mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:3.0.10
        4) javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0
  javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0
from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
[INFO] Unable to read jar manifest from C:\Users\arun.km\.m2\repository\javax\sql\jdbc-stdext\2.0\jdbc-stdext-2.0.jar
```

similarly 
Failed to retrieve javax.transaction:jta-1.0.1B

Comment: does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/33075830/4290096

Comment: There are no exclusions in my pom file. Right group id of jcs.jar solves the issue.

Comment: So your issue is solved ? Then you can add it as an answer .

Answer (score 2):

Solution Use the new Grounp : org.apache.jcs

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jcs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcs</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```