# Failure to find javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository,

Tags: java, maven

I am using Windows 10 pro x64, Apache Maven 3.6.3 .
My `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>vn.com.foobar</groupId>
    <artifactId>yyyy-xxxxxx</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>2.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <springframework.version>5.1.3.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <start-class>com.mp.server.Start</start-class>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xxxxxxjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxxxx-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
            <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
</project>
```

I already

- install a brand-new Maven 3.6.3,
- set `MAVEN_HOME`,
- delete all old things in `.m2` folder;
- Especially, I removed dependency `javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0`
- Copy source code of Java server-side project to a new directory.

then  I run

```
mvn package -X
```

So strange, I still catch error

> Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException:
>   Could not resolve dependencies for project
>   vn.com.foobar:xxx-xxxxxx:war:2.4.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find
>   javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
>   was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
>   until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Full log at https://pastebin.com/arwRbzTp . How to fix it?

Comment: open `.m2` folder and delete the files of your dependencies If I can read well `javax/sql/jdbc-stdext` or you to be sure delete all `javax` and try again

Comment: also, run a clean before package or `mvn clean:package -X`

Comment: Thank you, I already did like this, but I am not success.

Comment: does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075830/could-not-find-artifact-javax-sqljdbc-stdextjar2-0-in-central-https-repo-m

Comment: @YCF_L after run `mvn clean:package -X` this is my log https://pastebin.com/btdWcctC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary solution

download from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wbw20/maven-repository/master/releases/javax/sql/jdbc-stdext/2.0/jdbc-stdext-2.0.jar

run

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.sql -DartifactId=jdbc-stdext -Dversion=2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=jdbc-stdext-2.0.jar
```